# Vector with unique_ptr-s

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have code like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace daq
{

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(){};
};

class Pig : public Animal
{
public:
    Pig() : Animal () {};
};

class Farm
{
public:
    void addAnimal(Animal& animal)
    {
        mAnimals.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(animal)); // error
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> mAnimals;
};
} /* namespace daq */
```

But I get error in method Farm::addAnimal:

no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr(daq::Animal&)’

What should I pass to push_back method?

Comment: You should pass a pointer.

Comment: If you want to store dynamic copies (std::unique_ptr) of items that you receive _by reference_, you'll have to make the element type (Animal) cloneable somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` accepts a *pointer* as a constructor argument, but you are passing a *reference*. This is basically what the compiler is telling you: you can't construct a `std::unique_ptr` from a `daq::Animal&`.

You could pass a raw pointer to an object of type `Animal` allocated with `new`, or (preferably) you should pass a `unique_ptr` constructed that way and *move from it* when providing it as an argument of `push_back()`:

```
void addAnimal(std::unique_ptr<Animal>&& animal)
//                                    ^^
//                                    This is to make it absolutely clear that
//                                    your intention is to bind to an object
//                                    the client wants to move from. It is not
//                                    especially needed here (unique_ptr is not
//                                    copyable), but it makes your interface
//                                    more explicit about it. [Credits to sehe]
{
    mAnimals.push_back(std::move(animal)); // OK
}

int main()
{
    daq::Farm farm;
    std::unique_ptr<daq::Animal> pig(new daq::Pig());
    farm.addAnimal(std::move(pig)); // OK
}
```

You have to use `std::move()` here because `unique_ptr`s are non-copyable, so you are effectively transferring the ownership of `pig` from the routine that invokes it to the vector that contains it (`addAnimal()` being an intermediate in this transfer).

Comment: For reasons of style would it not be better to 'receive' the argument as an rvalue reference (documenting the move semantics)? `void addAnimal(std::unique_ptr<Animal>&& animal);`

Comment: @sehe: You mean, receive an `Animal&&` and do `farm.addAnimal(std::move(animal))`?

Comment: I mean *alter* the existing `addAnimal` (not add another overload)

Comment: @sehe: That's what I meant: alter the existing `addAnimal()` to receive an `Animal&&`, and invoke it by doing `farm.addAnimal(std::move(animal))`. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @sehe: That would defeat reference semantics I would say (although it is not clear whether it is needed here). The client may want to keep an observing pointer to the animal it adds to the farm. If reference semantics is not needed, on the other hand, then `mAnimals` could be a `vector<Animal>` and the argument of `addAnimal()` could be perfect-forwarded into `mAnimals`.

Comment: Oh. I misread [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704028/vector-with-unique-ptr-s/15704245?noredirect=1#comment22301573_15704245). No, obviously I just meant `void addAnimal(std::unique_ptr<Animal>&& animal);` (as I incidentally included in my first comment). Sorry for not reading too well

Comment: @sehe: Oh, I see, then in this case I'd say it makes sense, at least conceptually (after all, you're always going to pass an rvalue to `addAnimal()`). On the other hand, I'd say the compiler should be able to inline the call to the move constructor and turn it into a pointer assignment, which in terms of efficiency should be just as good as a reference binding. I am not 100% sure though, but yes, your suggestion makes sense

Comment: @sehe: Oh, not just a pointer assignment though, it must be at least two (since we're also nulling the pointer we moved from). So probably your suggestion is better - as long as we're concerned with saving one pointer assignment ;)

Comment: Don't forget about documentation value! In general, I think a 'std::move' without any indication in the interface is pretty bad. For move-only (noncopyable) types, this may not be relevant, but it seems important enough to keep the habit even there. (Literate programming?)